# El uso de un OR afecta al rendimiento de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo actualmente una consulta en SQL que básicamente me trae la información de unas transacciones, filtrándolo por fecha (para este ejemplo 1 mes).

Ésta es la consulta T-SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @FechaIni Date = '2022-12-01'
DECLARE @FechaFin Date = '2022-12-31'
DECLARE @Tipo INT =NULL --Todos

SELECT 
 t.NumeroTransaccion
,t.CodigoTransaccion
,s.numero_sucursal
,s.nombre_sucursal
FROM Transacciones t
INNER JOIN Sucursal s on s.numero_sucursal = t.numero_sucursal
WHERE (t.CodigoTransaccion IN ( 'BA', 'CASH' ) 
   OR (t.CodigoTransaccion IN ('PMNT', 'WCF') AND s.numero_sucursal =97))

AND t.FechaTransaccion BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin
AND (t.Status =@Tipo OR @Tipo IS NULL)
```

La consulta funciona muy bien. Básicamente obtiene las transacciones según el código de transacción.

En ese mes trae alrededor de 300.000 registros y tarda 1 minuto 30 segundos.

Sin embargo, al quitarle `s.numero_sucursal = 97` del `OR` la consulta tarda alrededor de 11 segundos.

Quisiera saber si así, como esta la consulta, es la mejor forma para utilizar el `OR` o existe alguna manera de trabajar con `OR` más optimizado.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, existen otros códigos de transacción además de "BA", "CASH", "PMMT" y "WCF" ???

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta que si `Transacciones.CodigoTransaccion` es un índice, el número de registros analizados será solo los que tengan los valores buscados. Al agregar aún más valores buscados, el tiempo puede aumentar en función de los registros que coincidan. Además, puede ser que `Sucursal.numero_sucursal` no sea un índice, lo que provocaría una lectura completa de la tabla `Sucursal` por cada registro de la tabla `Transacciones`. (continua)

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la definición de las tablas para poder darte una mejor ayuda en la optimización? También nos vendría bien un recuento aproximado de los registros que hay en cada tabla, así como el número de registros que coinciden con `BA`, `CASH`, etc haciendo un `SELECT CodigoTransaccion, COUNT(*) FROM Transacciones GROUP BY CodigoTransaccion`.

Comment: Al editar tu pregunta y organizarla para mejorar su lectura y comprensión me he dado cuenta que el problema no está en el `OR`, si no en uno de los operandos del `AND` dentro del `OR`. Redactando respuesta.

Comment: Puedes compartir la estructura de las tablas e índices que contienen así como un aproximado del número de filas que contienen?  Para tan pocas filas es demasiado tanto 1:30 minutos como 11 segundos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sin embargo, al quitarle s.numero_sucursal = 97 del OR la consulta tarda alrededor de 11 segundos.

Si la consulta reduce drásticamente su tiempo de ejecución quitando solo `s.numero_sucursal = 97` del `OR`, es muy probable que sea debido a que `Sucursal.numero_sucursal` no sea un índice.

En ese caso el motor de bases de datos necesita hacer un barrido de todos los registros en la tabla `Sucursal` por cada registro de la tabla `Transacciones` encontrado.

Creando un índice en ese campo (usando [`CREATE INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) conseguirás una reducción drástica en el tiempo de ejecución de la consulta:

```
CREATE INDEX numero_sucursal ON Sucursal (numero_sucursal)
```

PD: Olvidé comentar que esto mismo habría que hacerlo también en la tabla `Transacciones`:

```
CREATE INDEX numero_sucursal ON Transacciones (numero_sucursal)
```

También se podría agregar la pareja `numero_sucursal`/`CodigoTransaccion` y que la consulta fuera `t.CodigoTransaccion IN (..) AND t.numero_sucursal = ..`.

Comment: Una consulta, el indice debo crearlo al final de la consulta? o antes? disculpa nunca he usado indices

Comment: Necesitarías incluir el nombre_sucursal como columna incluida para que el índice no tenga que hacer un lookup para obtenerlo.

Comment: @Beterson la creación del índice se realiza una única vez y éste se queda creado de manera permanente para su uso.

Comment: @OscarGarcia de hecho las operaciones lookup, en especial cuando no hay un índice clustered, son más costosas que agregar la columna al índice en la sección de `INCLUDE`. Eso ahorra espacio y elimina lecturas del disco. No sé de donde sacas que todos los índices de todas las tablas deban de alojarse en memoria, para un buen rendimiento, ni siquiera necesitas que haya un índice completo en memoria, solo recuperar las páginas necesarias.

Comment: Es más, es probable que ese índice tenga que ser CLUSTERED y probablemente hasta la llave primaria, pero no conozco la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: [Creo que este tema es más interesante debatirlo en el chat para no molestar con comentarios en la respuesta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142535/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-luis-cazares).